# A Rhesus Macaque has stolen half my stuff!

Tags: dwarf-fortress

A Rhesus Macaque has come and stolen all my copper bars and picks.  What can I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for what you can do now, try to survive till the next trade caravan.  Then you'll be able to trade things for a new pick, which you'll need.

As for keeping this from happening?

- Traps
- Dogs

  - Dogs are the best defense against macaques because the macaques will actually stay away from them.
- Marksdwarves

  - They can kill the horrible monkey's before they're close enough to steal your implements.
- Wrestlers

  - If you have nothing better, at least the monkey's can't steal their weapons (though they may still steal their pants).

Comment: Will building doors and storing my stuff inside make a difference?  I want my pets to be able to go in and out but not the Rhesus Macaques.

Comment: @Mechko I and most players are not very trusting of doors.  It seems like most things can slip past them.

Answer (score 0):

There's not that much you can do really, except try to hunt down the macaque that stole your stuff and defend your fortress better. Note that they're kind of dangerous to an inexperienced force.

Comment: That'll teach me to try and teach my dogs to mine... :(  I was just about to build doors too.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the first thing you want to do, is mining for more copper with the miner you already have, as he is holding the last pick you have.

If you have found copper, you want to create some additional picks again and get back on your feet.

If however, you're unable to find copper, or don't have a miner anymore, you want try to survive on wooden stuff, until you can trade with the caravan, and regain picks/copper. (just remember not to trade wood stuff to the elves.)